# Pullback on differential forms are linear

Tags: differential-forms

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth transformation. Define the pullback $T^*: C^k (\mathbb{R}^m) \rightarrow C^k (\mathbb{R}^n)$ (With $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ being the set of functionals on $k$-cells on $\mathbb{R}^n$) by $T^*: Y \mapsto Y \circ T$.

Thus, the pullback of $Y \in C^k (\mathbb{R}^m)$ is the functional on $C_k (\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$T^*Y:\phi \mapsto Y(T\circ \phi)$$

Why is the pullback linear, and why does $(T \circ S)^* = S^* \circ T^*$?

Comment: Both facts follow from a direct verification: have you tried to simply use the definitions of everything in sight?

Comment: I guess it is just difficult for me to understand how to correctly manipulate $k$-cells.

Comment: Say you want to check that $(T\circ S)^*=S^*\circ T^*$. The two sides of the equality are functions, so to chck equality you need to apply both sides to an element of their domain and use their definitions to compute: the two results must be equal.

Comment: Alright, is it actually this easy then?

$$(T \circ S)^* (Y) = Y \circ (T \circ S)$$

and 

$$S^* \circ T^*(Y) = S^* (Y \circ T) = Y \circ T \circ S$$

and to show linearity:

$$T^*(aY + X) = (aY + X)(T) = aY(T) + X(T)$$

Comment: Yes :) (Although in the part about linearity you are missing a few $\circ$s.)

Comment: Please, do write an answer explaining how you solved this, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be arbitrary functionals (and $a$ an arbitrary constant). Since linearity is preserved on $k$-forms:

\begin{align}
T^*(aY + X) &= (aY + X) \circ T \\
&= (aY + X) (T) \\
&= aY(T) + X(T) \\
&= aT^*(Y) + T^*(X).
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(T \circ S)^* (Y) &= Y \circ (T \circ S) \\
&= Y \circ T \circ S \\
&= S^*(Y \circ T) \\
&= S^* \circ T^* (Y).
\end{align}